# Learning Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am an Oracle PL/SQL developer. I have a new project, which requires oracle forms knowledge. I have not even seen a forms page, kindly guide me how to start with learning oracle forms.

Is it possible to install forms in a laptop ?  Are there any developer version of oracle forms like we have Oracle XE.

Which is the most used version or Oracle forms ?

How long does it take to learn forms, considering my above background and for a average learner :P :)

Any pdf or pointer to you tube channels will of great help

Comment: Till about one year ago, Oracle Form's documentation was ridiculously poor and I'm not aware of any interest of Oracle to change this. If you are an experienced SQL developer and got your fingers wet with, say, MS-Access, then you should be able to learn quite rapidly. Installing in a laptop is indeed possible. Be aware that it does NOT like when the installation path has blanks (e.g. if you installed under the folder `\My experience with ORAForms\Here` it will not work. Last, why would anyone wish to develop a new project using such an old, incredibly heavy platform?

Comment: - Oracle forms can be installed on laptop
- What is the most used version? I suppose that there is a lot of old software written with old version of forms; anyway version 6 is the last version that is both client/server and web; the next ones, 9, 10 and so on are only web
- in my opinion is easy, an official course can be 15 days long, but, as always, is practice that skills you
- try http://coldiarrive.xyz/read-book/oracle-forms-developer-build-internet-applications-volume-1-instructor-guide.pdf